# What is reverse engineering, and how to learn it?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, reverse

What is reverse engineering in Android and how can that be achieved? What are the pros and cons, and how to learn reverse engineering?

I have already tried this: [Android reengineering : extract and protect APK's resources (technical questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160304/android-reengineering-extract-and-protect-apks-resources-technical-questions), but I cant really understand it.

Comment: Please do a google search instead. Look for laws and case law in your particular jurisdiction especially. Reverse engineering has a pretty fuzzy definition, both in real life and legally speaking, depending exactly on what you're intending to do, and this is not a legal forum. Legal explanations or clarifications are completely off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal explanations or legal clarifications are completely off topic here.

Comment: `Pros`? **Stealing** the work of other developers, like a **parasite**. `Cons`? It's **illegal**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse engineering: analyzing a product to determine how it was made.

Re-engineering: making a copy of a product from scratch (often using the results of reverse engineering).

Speaking as an industry veteran, it's really not possible to prevent reverse-engineering. And really not worth trying to prevent it. A determined hacker can reverse pretty much anything, including far more sophisticated protection schemes than you will ever be able to make yourself. (e.g. compile a custom version of the Android operating system with added hooks to capture encrypted APKs as they are decrypted. If it runs, you can capture it. Not much you can do about that).

Anyone who's determined to break the law can and will break your protection scheme, assuming you have something worth swiping which you probably do not. Anyone who isn't interested in breaking the law wont steal your code or resources.

Your tools for protecting your code are copyright law and patent law. Not copy protection. Don't bother copy-protecting your stuff. It's a wasted effort.

Comment: thanks now its clear..

Comment: i would better not get into reverse engineering instead create my own code